# Need help filling in box plot with custom colors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, boxplot

Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(15,4)))

#Rename columns
data.set_axis(['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D'], axis=1, inplace=True)

data

     Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
0    0.786186   -0.416792    0.174680    2.487244
1   -0.252369   -0.342730    0.205828   -1.321883
2   -2.000831   -1.710470    1.230441    1.151613
3    1.589489   -0.735494   -1.427740   -0.291532
4    0.162657    0.091248   -1.166623   -1.702915
5   -2.046027    0.538372    1.799922   -1.283141
6   -0.046736   -0.100009   -0.775107    1.778775
7   -0.205502   -1.033712    0.335681    0.178957
8   -0.598907    1.863979   -0.828703   -0.977883
9   -0.532970   -0.964670   -1.618440    0.169850
10   2.123033    0.472480    2.307614   -0.397944
11   1.149670   -0.906352    0.409004   -1.322099
12   0.618216   -1.181656    0.342085   -0.853023
13  -1.108748   -0.546607   -3.468131   -0.382351
14  -0.404277   -1.612273    0.787983    1.033892

#Create figure 
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (15,15))

#Colors I want to use
colors = ['#002072', '#00BDF2']
```

**I want to create a box plot of my data in the axs[0] subplot (the top subplot in the figure I have created) and fill in the bar colors as shown below. Notice how the colors alternate.** I have provided the hex color codes of the colors I want. **I also want to change the color of the median/mean line so that it's easier to see in the dark blue bars.** I really appreciate any help. I've been struggling with this for hours. You would think it would be as simple as passing an argument, but I have not had success with the example code I've found online. I get more confused the more examples I come across.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) or another more powerful library than just `matplotlib`:

```
import seaborn as sns

# Let's melt the data first into long format.
df = df.melt()

# You appear to have two groups, let's make them:
df['group'] = df.variable.isin(['Column A', 'Column C'])

colors = ['#002072', '#00BDF2']

sns.boxplot(data=df, y='variable', x='value', hue='group', palette=colors)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Your question is a bit too broad, let's start with just the one question of coloring. After this, look through the documentation on your own, do a little bit of Googling... and if you still can't figure out the excess parts of your question, feel free to make a new question~

Comment: This helps. Given that you are using seaborn, if I want to make further changes to the plot (change labels, annotate plot with text, change x-axis ticks, etc.) can I still do this through the axs[0] subplot object I pass when I call sns.boxplot()? In other words, do axes objects with sns plots still support matplotlib functionality?

Comment: I would assume so... best way to check is by running it yourself!

Comment: yes. seaborn is built on matplotlib. I don't like saying seaborn is more powerful than matplotlib. They are the same thing. seaborn just abstracts all the manual building of plots to some simplified functions. But you have access to all the underlying matplotlib axes.

Answer (score 1):

I like to suggest you this code but, you should improve the code based on your data.

```
# Import libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating dataset
np.random.seed(10)
data_1 = np.random.normal(100, 10, 200)
data_2 = np.random.normal(90, 20, 200)
data_3 = np.random.normal(80, 30, 200)
data_4 = np.random.normal(70, 40, 200)
data = [data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4]

fig = plt.figure(figsize =(10, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Creating axes instance
bp = ax.boxplot(data, patch_artist = True,
                notch ='True', vert = 0)

colors = ['#0000FF', '#00FF00',
        '#FFFF00', '#FF00FF']

for patch, color in zip(bp['boxes'], colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)

# changing color and linewidth of
# whiskers
for whisker in bp['whiskers']:
    whisker.set(color ='#8B008B',
                linewidth = 1.5,
                linestyle =":")

# changing color and linewidth of
# caps
for cap in bp['caps']:
    cap.set(color ='#8B008B',
            linewidth = 2)

# changing color and linewidth of
# medians
for median in bp['medians']:
    median.set(color ='red',
            linewidth = 3)

# changing style of fliers
for flier in bp['fliers']:
    flier.set(marker ='D',
            color ='#e7298a',
            alpha = 0.5)
    
# x-axis labels
ax.set_yticklabels(['Column A', 'Column B',
                    'Column C', 'Column D'])

# Adding title
plt.title("Customized box plot")

# Removing top axes and right axes
# ticks
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()
    
# show plot
plt.show()
```

The Output
[Customize Box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bva8n.png)